# Illegal request error in spray.io

Tags: scala, spray

I'm building a web server with spray.io, and I keep getting the following error when I run basic requests:

```
Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': Illegal request:
Cannot establish effective request URI of HttpRequest(GET,/,List(Accept: */*, Host: :3000, User-Agent: curl/7.30.0),Empty,HTTP/1.1),
request has a relative URI and an empty `Host` header
```

I'm running Spray version 1.3.1 and Akka version 2.3.2.

I have a basic `WebService` class that serves as a basis for other services:

```
trait WebService extends HttpService {
  implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
}
```

And on that basis I've built a basic service:

```
trait TestService extends WebService {
  val testRoute: Route = {
    pathPrefix("test") {
      get {
        complete("OK")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone run into this problem before? I get the feeling that there's probably just some tiny thing that I'm missing.

Comment: It looks like the http request path is "/" but your route is "/test"  can you confirm you are requesting the right route?

Comment: My bad. I usually curl `localhost` plus a port using an environment variable, and it turns out that I didn't set the variable when I re-installed Ubuntu. Very dumb of me. Thanks.